# Hazelcast caller member throws timeout exception when a serialization exception happens on callee member

Tags: java, hazelcast, unparseable

I'm using **Hazelcast** (JAVA, version 3.7.5) in a scenario with **2 members**. The first member delegates a task to the second member through an `IExecutorService`. After some processing, the second member tries to send back an **unserializable response**.

As it's not possible to send back a response, the **second member** prints the stacktrace related to the `HazelcastSerializationException`.

As no response arrives, the **first member** throws an `OperationTimeoutException` when the *operation-heartbeat-timeout* is reached.

Currently, when the IExecutorService fails at parsing the Callable result, it prints a stacktrace (on callee side).
Let say I have a simple caller :

```
private Future<Object> startFlow() {
    //This throws an OperationTimeoutException
    return hazelcastInstance.getExecutorService("myExecutor").submit(myRunnable);
}
```

Which calls a simple callee :

```
@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    //The object returned is not serializable, therefore an HazelcastSerializationException is thrown
    return service.execute();
}
```

The callee prints a stacktrace after it failed to parse the response (see end of post).

In my case, it's not possible to know what kind of object the `service` might return, and it's not possible to trust the `service` to send back serializable objects.

**I would like to be able to know the reason of the timeout on the caller-side.**

After some search, I found that no configuration/API is available to intercept exceptions thrown by an IExecutorService when it fails to serialize a response.

So I tried to see if it would be possible to check if an object was parseable by Hazelcast, again without success.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

---

The stacktrace printed by the callee will be looking like this :

```
Exception in thread "hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-1" com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.responses.NormalResponse'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:73)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:143)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:124)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationServiceImpl.send(OperationServiceImpl.java:427)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.RemoteInvocationResponseHandler.sendResponse(RemoteInvocationResponseHandler.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:291)
    at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.DistributedExecutorService$CallableProcessor.sendResponse(DistributedExecutorService.java:269)
    at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.DistributedExecutorService$CallableProcessor.run(DistributedExecutorService.java:253)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Failed to serialize 'com.myomain.UnserialiableObject'
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleSerializeException(SerializationUtil.java:73)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:236)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:371)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.responses.NormalResponse.writeData(NormalResponse.java:91)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:189)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:54)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:140)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class com.myomain.UnserialiableObject
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.serializerFor(AbstractSerializationService.java:469)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:232)
    ... 18 more
```

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**

So I ended up registering a global serializer, that would simply send an Exception whenever it's called. Something like this :

```
public class GlobalSerializerException  implements StreamSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void write(ObjectDataOutput out, Object object) throws IOException {
        String objectInfo;
        if(object == null){
            objectInfo = "Object was null.";
        }else{
            objectInfo = String.format("Object of class %s and printed as String gives %s", object.getClass().getCanonicalName(), object.toString());
        }
        objectInfo = "Hazelcast was unable to serialize an object. " + objectInfo;
        out.writeUTF(objectInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public Object read(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        String message = in.readUTF();
        HazelcastSerializationException hazelcastSerializationException = new HazelcastSerializationException(message);
        return hazelcastSerializationException;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTypeId() {
        return 63426;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caller fails with a timeout because it doesn't get a response from the target. Target node fails to serialize the response, as a reason fails to send a response. This is current behaviour but I think it's also possible to send a special exception to denote that response failure too.

Hazelcast, by default, is able to serialize classes implementing `java.io.Serializable`, `java.io.Externalizable` and some Hazelcast specific interfaces, such as [DataSerializable](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/nio/serialization/DataSerializable.html), [Portable](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/nio/serialization/Portable.html). It's also possible to define custom serializers or delegate to another serialization library. See [Hazelcast Reference Manual - Serialization](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#serialization) section for more info.

In a distributed system, messages exchanged between nodes must be serializable to a binary form to transmit them through network. So, an entity/service participating in a distributed system must ensure its messages are serializable in some form.

If you don't know the type of the messages, then you can register Hazelcast a [global serializer](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#global-serializer), which first tries to serialize using known formats (`Serializable`, `Externalizable` etc), if type is not known then it writes a custom error message instead. 
Alternatively, you can wrap result of the service's execution with a custom serializable wrapper object. During serialization, if original wrapped result fails to serialize, then you again write a custom error message.

For example;

```
class NonSerializableResponseException extends Exception {}

class ServiceResponseWrapper implements DataSerializable {

    private Object response;

    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        try {
            out.writeObject(response);
        } catch (HazelcastSerializationException e) {
            out.writeObject(new NonSerializableResponseException());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        response = in.readObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try both suggestions to see what happens.